# HIkariCP: connection leaks and usage time

Tags: hikaricp

I was wondering whether connection leaks and usage time are correlating.

A connection leak is identified if a connection is out of the pool for an amount of time over the configured leakDetectionThreshold.
Is this amount of time the same as the connection usage time?

I am asking because I am seeing some connection leaks with a leakDetectionThreshold of 30s whereas I cannot find any connections with a corresponding connection usage time.

Thanks,
Michail

Comment: Same questions asked in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/977Mlduzkg8 but received no answer so far

Answer (score 0):

Connection usage time, as reported by Dropwizard metrics, is recorded using a Histogram with an exponentially decaying reservior.  Quoting their doc:

> A histogram with an exponentially decaying reservoir produces
>   quantiles which are representative of (roughly) the last five minutes
>   of data. It does so by using a forward-decaying priority reservoir
>   with an exponential weighting towards newer data.

As such, I think it would be very difficult to correlate individual connection leaks with any particular quartile in the histogram.